# How to use defaultImpl property of @JsonTypeInfo annotation?

Tags: json, jackson

I want to use **defaultImpl** property of **@JsonTypeInfo** annotation to deal the case when type information is missing during deserialization.

I used above property as mentioned below.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class" ,defaultImpl = DefaultImpl.class)

public class DefaultImpl{
}
```

Problems is I do not know what can I write in this class to deal with missing type information.

Please help me, example will be nice to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write anything in the class for missing type information: if it is missing, this class is chosen that is all. But it obviously needs to have place to databind properties, or be configured to ignore unknown properties.